# npm install not able to establish connection inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running docker on ubuntu 16.04. While trying to make my nodejs app inside docker container accessible by https, I made a few changes to port mapping like so:-

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:443:8443/tcp bookshelf-server:0.1 bash                                                                                                                    
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8443/tcp bookshelf-server:0.1 bash
```

because I was trying to map port 8443 as I was listening to it for https

This did not work, but it broke my npm install inside docker container. Or maybe something else might have broken it as I was not testing it while trying experiments.

Nevertheless, now when `npm run install` runs from the docker container, it gives the following error :-

```
Step 5/13 : RUN npm install       
---> Running in 7c78745fb509                                                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED                                                                                                                                                                                         
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED                                                                                                                                                                                        
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.22.35:443                                                                                       
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
```

I reckon I might have messed up some port connections or something, can anyone give me a direction of how to debug the issue.
Thanks